# Exclude sender from receiving event (Greenrobot's Eventbus)

Tags: android, greenrobot-eventbus

I have a class which is sender and receiver of objects (of one type) that are put on the Eventbus.

Is there a way to exclude the sender from the receiving of the event? I have multiple senders and only want to receive the events from other senders but from myself.

Example:

A puts RED on the Bus. Receiver C and D get the event RED. But also A (because it is registered for color events) gets RED. Can this be avoided? So in this case (A is sender) A should not be receiver?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't think greenrobot supports this. As a workaround, you could either modify `Color` to have a `sender` field that contains a reference to the sender, or wrap `Color` in another class that has the `sender` field. Then, the `A` event handler method could do a `if (event.sender != this)` test before acting on the event.

Comment: Im using the hashcode of the sender and ignore these events in the sender's on receive.

Comment: A hashcode is not unique, so your approach is not safe. You should just pass a reference to the object, as I suggested.